# QGIS' georeferencer layer doesn't appear?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I use QGIS 1.8.0 for Linux, and I want to draw roads manually on the map.

[image]

So according some tutorials, I use `Raster>Geoferencer>Geoferencer` to import a bitmap image including roads, and set Geoferencer like this screenshot.

However, after "Start geoferencing", the Geoferencer layer didn't appear on the map. Just like this:

[image]

I've tried move the reference layer to top and toggle "update drawing order" but it doesn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: Which coordinate reference systems (Layer/Project CRS) are you using?

Comment: TWD67, and all of my layer set as that(including georeferencer)

Comment: What happens if you "Zoom to Layer Extend" (right click)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look for `Settings -> Options`, CRS Tab

under `CRS for new Layer`, you should activate `Ask for CRS`. and choose your custom CRS.

Standard is EPSG:4326, and the coordinates of your tif are most probably outside the allowed bounds of +-180°/90° of lon/lat coordinates.

Comment: All of my layer is TWD67-TM2(a common CRS used in Taiwan), including groreferencer. But it doesn't work when georefrencing.

Comment: Qgis Master offers EPSG:3827 and 3828 for that CRS. If you don't want to use that, you can use current GDAL to reproject the tif to a CRS known in your Qgis Lisboa.

Comment: Have tried, but doesn't work :(

Comment: Your screenshot shows EPSG:3857 as project CRS. If you have grabbed the georeference points from the screen, you have to set the target CRS also to EPSG:3857.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found that following the instructions at [OpenLayers Plugin Error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57561/openlayers-plugin-error-latitude-or-longitude-exceeded-limits) worked.  They are:

- set the project CRS to EPSG:3857
- make sure on-the-fly-projection is enabled
- add the background openlayers map layer you want load other stuff
  that might have other layer CRS, like WGS84 in lat/lon degrees
- save the project

After this georeferencing the image map with CRS EPSG:3857 worked.  I wish I knew why.

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me too, so weird...

Answer (score 1):

Try converting the image to be referenced to a jpg instead of a bitmap, it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Select parameters as following:

- Transformation type : Linear
- Sampling Method : Nearest Neighbor
- Select proper projection system

Screenshot is attached herewith[image]