# OpenLayers Plugin Error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I'm aware the 'traceback' OpenLayers plugin error has been dealt with before.

Unfortunately for me, the solutions posted were way over my head, e.g. using workarounds and code posted on github, etc. I find it all mind-boggling.

The error message reads:

```
An error has occured while executing Python code:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/MCMA1580/.qgis//python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 48, in addLayer
    self.__plugin.addLayer(self)
  File "C:/Users/MCMA1580/.qgis//python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 190, in addLayer
    self.__setMapSrsGoogle()
  File "C:/Users/MCMA1580/.qgis//python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 249, in __setMapSrsGoogle
    extMap = coodTrans.transform(extMap, QgsCoordinateTransform.ForwardTransform)
QgsCsException: forward transform of
(0.884883, 2.549197)
PROJ.4: +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +to +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext  +no_defs
Error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Safest way to start the openlayers plugin is to

- set the **project** CRS to EPSG:3857
- make sure `on-the-fly-projection` is enabled
- add the background openlayers layer you want
- load other stuff that might have other **layer** CRS, like WGS84 in lat/lon  degrees
- save the project