# How to re-project shapefile to be compatible with Openlayers satellite imagery

Tags: qgis, openlayers-2, coordinate-system

The goal: Visualize a map using google's satellite (and projection) using my collected points.

Right now I have a shapefile of my collected points from surveying. I created it by adding my csv file. The shapefile is working and has a projection of WGS 84/ UTM 48N. My coordinates are in decimal degrees.

When I try on the fly projection to EPSG:3857 following the steps provided in this answered question: [OpenLayers Plugin Error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57561/openlayers-plugin-error-latitude-or-longitude-exceeded-limits)

I get my points in the same relative position, but can only be seen at a scale of 11:1 or greater. This also makes it so the points show up in the wrong location. (13N 112E shows up on Sumatra--the island) Why is this/how can I fix it? The scale should be more like 1:1000.

Running Mac OSX Yosemite, QGIS 2.6.1 (have tried 2.4.x and 2.6.0), OpenLayers 1.3.6

Comment: At the moment I think you are trying to answer three questions which you have enumerated in a numbered list.  As per the [Tour] we advocate one question per question which here I think is critical to try and line up your three symptoms with the precise procedure that led to each.  I recommend that you edit your question to focus it on one of these symptoms and the precise steps that led to you seeing it.  You can always research/ask about the other two separately.

Comment: A couple of your actual points in various projections might help too.

Answer (score 2):

`WGS 84/ UTM 48N. My coordinates are in decimal degrees` is a contradiction.

If they are in decimal degrees, you **must** set the layer CRS to EPSG:4326, not any UTM system which has meters as units.

From that point, use `Rightclick, Save As ...` to another filename and EPSG:3857 as CRS.

With the **project** CRS set to EPSG:3857 and Oepnlayers background tiles, the points will show up where you expect them.

And please, **never** **use** `Set CRS for Layer` again. It does **not** reproject the coordinates.

Comment: "And please, never use `Set CRS for Layer again`. It does not reproject the coordinates." Can you explain the purpose of this feature please? Does it reproject anything? I also did this when I first started using QGIS. As you have mentioned (a few hundred times in your answers!) that layers should always be saved using the **Save As...** and set the CRS from there, what is the point of having the option available when right-clicking. Oh, and +1 :)

Comment: There are shapefiles (or csv data) without CRS. If you think that the CRS assigned by QGIS as default is wrong, you can change that to something making sense. Or try some promising CRS's to find the one fitting best. This tool moves your points around, while `Save As` lets them stay at the same spot on the world.