# Using OpenLayers plugin Python?

Tags: python, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I am having problems opening the OpenLayers plugin (any of them).  It seems to be a Python error. I have searched around in previous questions to find something, but none of the solutions I came across fixed the issue.

I have posted the error message below:

```
An error has occurred while executing Python code: 

QgsCsException: forward transform of (-140537588568161501184.000000, -99802055649825423360.000000) PROJ.4:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to  +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs Error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Russells/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\weblayers\weblayer.py", line 100, in addLayer
    self._addLayerCallback(self)
  File "C:/Users/Russells/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 158, in addLayer
    self.setMapCrs(coordRefSys)
  File "C:/Users/Russells/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_plugin.py", line 206, in setMapCrs
    extMap = coordTrans.transform(extMap, QgsCoordinateTransform.ForwardTransform)
QgsCsException: forward transform of
(-140537588568161501184.000000, -99802055649825423360.000000)
PROJ.4:  +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 +to  +proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs
Error: latitude or longitude exceeded limits


Python version: 2.7.5 (default, May 15 2013, 22:44:16) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] 
QGIS version: 2.18.0 Las Palmas, 0332f5a 

Python Path:
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins\processing
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python
C:/Users/Russells/.qgis2/python
C:/Users/Russells/.qgis2/python/plugins
C:/PROGRA~1/QGIS2~1.18/apps/qgis/./python/plugins
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib-1.3.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\nose-1.3.3-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\tornado-4.0.1-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\backports.ssl_match_hostname-3.4.0.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\certifi-14.05.14-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin\python27.zip
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\DLLs
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\plat-win
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\lib-tk
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\bin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\jinja2-2.7.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\markupsafe-0.23-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\pytz-2012j-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\win32\lib
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\Shapely-1.2.18-py2.7-win-amd64.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.8-msw-unicode
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlrd-0.9.2-py2.7.egg
C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS2~1.18\apps\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt-0.7.5-py2.7.egg
C:/Users/Russells/.qgis2//python
F:/School/History/Mapping/AtlantaCampaign
```

Comment: Have you tried the solution posted here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/57561/openlayers-plugin-error-latitude-or-longitude-exceeded-limits

Comment: @lpdudley I did. Just tried it again, this was the code that came back:

Comment: 2016-11-14T14:04:45 1 Traceback (most recent call last):
     File "C:/Users/Russells/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_layer.py", line 125, in request
       self.setup_map()
     File "C:/Users/Russells/.qgis2/python/plugins\openlayers_plugin\openlayers_layer.py", line 201, in setup_map
       olSize = QSize(int(olWidth), int(olHeight))
   TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
     QSize(): too many arguments
     QSize(int, int): argument 1 has unexpected type 'long'
     QSize(QSize): argument 1 has unexpected type 'long'